# Wifi not working - Ubuntu 12.04/14.04 LTS - Realtek 802.11d RTL8192EE

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, wireless, realtek

I have recently got a new machine, a lenovo thinkpad T440s. I am trying Ubuntu 12.04 on it and it cannot find my wifi. I believe this is due to missing the driver for my network adapter. It's 2x2 11b/g/n Wireless LAN M.2 (Realtek 802.11d RTL8192EE). I've been trying to find this answer elsewhere, but all I've surmised is that ubuntu really doesn't like these realtek network adapters. The downloads for the drivers I've found are all for windows, as well.

Note: I am a linux/configuration n00b, so please assume 0 knowledge of how to do anything on the terminal, etc.

Any suggestions?

Update: Switched to 12.04 because 13.10 is no longer supported. Same issue.

My current guess is that there is currently no open source support for the proprietary drivers, ergo, there is perhaps no solution within Ubuntu. If this is the case, could anyone suggest what my options may be? Are there any workarounds, or another distro which would support it - or is this native to the entire linux kernel?

Update 2: It doesn't work on 14.04 either.

Update 3: I followed the instructions here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2190347&page=2
Didn't work.
Here is the output of the script: http://pastie.org/9686848
Here is the output of lshw: http://pastie.org/9686851
rfkill list showed nothing blocked: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

Comment: Hi travisb, is it possible for you to upgrade to 14.04 or even 14.10. This way we can help you better since 13.10 is officially not supported. You can see which versions are still supported in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_14.10_.28Utopic_Unicorn.29

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately not 14 (specifically not compatible with the development work I'm doing at present), but I can go down to 12.04. I'll try that out I suppose and update if that solves this issue I'm having.

Comment: @travisb keep in mind downgrading is pretty tricky, you might want to back up what data you need and then clean install 12.04.

Comment: No worries. It's a fresh machine that I'm doing this on. (moving to a new dev machine). I appreciate the warning, though. :)

Comment: Updated using 12.04. Same issue is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by upgrading to Ubuntu 14.10. It will recognize this driver properly. However, it seems Ubuntu 14.04 and 12.04, the LTS ones, unfortunately still don't work no matter what I tried. If anyone has an answer for the LTS OS versions, please post it for others to know!