# What to do when you install a new Wifi card?

Tags: wireless, drivers

I have a wifi card that has a really buggy driver which is causing my system to freeze and the network to randomly disconnect. I bought a new Intel wifi card (the previous one is from Realtek). The problem is how do I prepare my computer? Will Ubuntu automatically detect a new wifi card and switch drivers for me or what?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to debug the existing driver/card combination? What card is it? lspci -nn | grep 0280 Thanks.

Comment: I have a rtl8192ee driver for realtek wireless adapter. I've looked up the bug for this driver and apparently there is no fix available yet. So right now my only option is to swap my wireless card.

Comment: Did you read this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/541697/wifi-not-working-ubuntu-12-04-14-04-lts-realtek-802-11d-rtl8192ee/547309#547309

Comment: @chili555 Yeah, I've been at this problem for a week now. I can connect to the internet, but there are lots of problems. For instance, after suspending the laptop, the wifi will not come up again. Also, the driver is causing random hard lockups. The driver is written really hastily I'm guessing and I don't want to deal with it, especially since this is the laptop I use to get work done. $30 for an intel wifi chip is nothing compared to the time I could waste trying to solve all the subtle annoying bugs.

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are physically removing the old card and installing a different card in the machine, it shouldn't be necessary to do anything about the drivers. Drivers for most Intel cards and the required firmware are installed by default in recent Ubuntu versions.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it did not appear automatically after a reboot.

So I created a USB-Cable-Hotspot with my phone.
I guess that having internet Ubuntu was able to download drivers for the card automatically. (Using an ethernet cable was my first idea - but the router was far away)